# set values in form fields in edit mode when data comes from multipal tables

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am developing a custom module for a project. I created a custom form and that custom form's data saved in two tables. Now when form open in edit mode I am not able to get saved data from both tables. I have no idea how can I get resolve this issue, please help me.

Here are my two tables structures:

Table1-

```
-------------------------
id | page_id | title

1  |  3      |  ABC

2  | 4       |  PQRS

3  | 10      |  XYZ
```

Table2-

```
--------------------------------
id | page_id | child  | position

1  | 3       |  8     |  left

2  | 3       |  7     |  right

3  | 3       |  15    |  right

4  | 4       |  14    |  right

5  | 4       |  15    |  left

6  | 10      |  15    |  left

--------------------------------
```

Here i am attaching a screen-shot to more explain myself. I want to selected saved option values in 'left' & 'right' text-area  in edit mode, values comes from table2.

[image: form fields]

Please suggest me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solutions of my query. 
This extension is the best example [click here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalog/product/view/id/19365/s/page-summary-block-4069/)

To get resolve this need to edit many files like model, resource and block files. That's why I mentioned this link to understand complete process.
most file that are need attention are :

- app/code/community/[PackageName]/[ModuleName]/Model/Resource/Pagesummary.php
- app/code/community/[PackageName]/[ModuleName]/Model/Pagesummary.php
- app/code/community/[PackageName]/[ModuleName]/Block/Adminhtml/Cms/Page/Edit/Tab/Pagesummary.php

hope this helps others!

Answer (score 0):

Left and Right are here multiselect field types and these kind of fields receives values in comma separated string. so the example you presented will work in this way.
lets consider you have models Table1 and Table2 and you pass your Table Model from edit action in you controller you have written

```
$table1Id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
$table1Model  = Mage::getModel('page/table1')->load($table1Id);
if ($table1Model->getId()) {
         Mage::register('page_data', $table1Model);
...
```

In your form file Block/Adminhtml/Edit/Tab/Form.php there is method $form->setData()

```
if ( Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getPageData() )
    {
        $form->setValues(Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getPageData());
        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setPageData(null);
    } 
elseif ( Mage::registry('page_data') ) {
$values = Mage::registry('page_data')->getData();
$values['left'] = '8';//You can get this value from Table2 collection on basis of $values['page_id'] you got
$values['right'] = '7,15';////You can get this value from Table2 collection on basis of $values['page_id'] you got
        $form->setValues($values);
    }
```